# Are input/output nodes only a fiction?

Tags: quantum-gate, quantum-circuit

When running quantum algorithms, are input and output nodes of any gate in a quantum circuit two separate sets of (physical qubit) nodes, or are we only mutating/overwriting one fixed set of nodes? Because, from pictures, I am a bit confused - they look like two sets and immutable.

Answer (score 4):

In quantum circuits, the qubits are represented with the "wires" (the horizontal lines on which gates are chained) rather than "input" and "output" nodes. They usually start in the $|0\rangle$ state, their state changes as the gates are applied, and the classical output is the readout of the measurement nodes.

Answer (score 1):

In superconducting quantum computers, gates are implemented with microwave pulses. So, the gates do not have input/output nodes (wires) in classical sense. It it true, that qubits are connected among each other (although not always fully) with coupling capacitors in order to apply two-qubits gates, however, again they are microwave pulses. Another physical realization of a quantum computer, e.g. photonic, trapped ions etc., implements gates with laser pulses. So, again there are no wires.